# How do you interact with smartcontract on jpg.store

Tags: smart-contract, nft, datum

Does anyone know how you interact with smart contract on jpg. store

Do we need this?
https://github.com/jpg-store/current-jpg-store-contracts

if so how do we do so?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can. Validator are sent with the transaction, so you either have the source code or their CBOR to add to your transaction.

When they move to Vasil and Plutus V2 you'll have reference scripts with that you only need to find a transaction to get the reference to the script.